# Reordering columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

So i am new to matlab so forgive me if this is a straightforward question. How can i take the i'th column of an mxn matrix A such that it becomes the new n'th column. I don't want to swap the i'th and n'th columns. To be clearer , the main n'th column is to become the (n-1)'th column.

Comment: `A` = `A(:,[1:i-1 i+1:n i])`. Or `A` = `A(:,[1:i-1 i+1:end i])`

Comment: you want to copy the column? or move it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move column i to column n:

```
A = A(:, [1:i-1 i+1:n i]); % result is same size as original
```

To copy column i and append it after column n:

```
A = A(:, [1:n i]); % result has 1 more column
```